# Can you set hibernate to drop tables before (re)creating it

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I have an oracle database and a spring API written in Java. I'm trying to get it to drop my tables, before hibernate recreates it on startup. If the tables do not exist, they will be created as expected and I can see the status of their creating in the console output. However, I then can't drop and recreate them if I stop and rerun it.

I've got the hibernate settings set in an application.properties file *(included below)* but nothing i've tried has worked.

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.generate_ddl=true
hibernate.generate_ddl-auto=update
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

> I've tried changing the update for create-drop with no luck.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can change `hibernate.generate_ddl-auto=update` to `hibernate.generate_ddl-auto=create-drop` or try `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop`

If Spring JPA is being used the property required is `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

Comment: "I've tried changing the update for create-drop with no luck."
I've tried both solutions.

Comment: I have, yes. Nothing I've tried seems to drop the tables. :(

Comment: Are you using Spring JPA?

Comment: `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` drops table on startup. Check your server logs, there you can find `Drop table if exists <your table name>`

Comment: Yes, Spring JPA. (I think!!) --- There's no database related lines in the log file. I only get anything DB related if I manually drop the tables before restarting, then it show the create table stuff. I'd post a copy of the log file, but I'm unsure how.

Comment: I;ve tried spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create and creat-auto. Nothing. :(